# How to get user properties after user log into WSO2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Here is my steps

My OAuth Endpoint:
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost/gatewaytest/Home/WsoCallBack

Then i got code and got access token by this
"https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token"

Then i invoke this endpoint
"https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid"

then i got result like this
{"sub":"Alexwso1.com"}

How can i get other properties like email,phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Navigate to your service provider configuration in WSO2 IS (path
   through management console: Main Menu-> Service Providers -> List ->
   Select the SP), and expand “Claim Configuration”.
2. Then add the corresponding claims for the user attributes you need,
   in the `requested claims` section.

[image]

Re-do your flow by starting getting the authorization code, access token, and user info. If the local claims you added in step (2) are mapped to an oidc claim in the http://wso2.org/oidc/claim dialect you will be able to get that user info.

Otherwise follow this guide https://medium.com/@inthiraj1994/lets-add-a-custom-claim-to-oidc-in-wso2-is-d871e418d6b0